# CFBundleVersion of another app on the device

Tags: ios, ios6

I can get the version of my app by doing this:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]
```

But how do I get the version of another app on the device? I want to know if an app is up to date for valid document sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the version of another app. If you can control the other app add a new url scheme to the new version of the app.

Comment: I'm not sure how adding a custom URL scheme allows an app to discover the version of the app.

Comment: @rmaddy It does not allow you to get the exact version of the app. I assumed the document sharing was done via url schemes. If that is the case, you can use a new url scheme for the new version of the app and use this scheme while sharing documents. The app will only be able to open this scheme if it is up-to-date.

Comment: That's how I'm going to use it.

Comment: OK, I see. Adding an additional URL scheme that represents the new format. That will work but it doesn't scale well. What happens if there is a need for this on every update due to document format updates? I guess you could keep adding `myScheme1`, `myScheme2`, ..., `myScheme12`, etc.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, you are right. It won't scale well if you need to do it for every new version of the app.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. An app has no access to the details about another installed app.

However, if you are writing both apps then there is a trick but it requires that the apps have been run at least once after any update. Your two apps can share a private named pasteboard. If the apps write their own current version to the private pasteboard, each app can read the value stored by the other app.